# Apache Ignite REST API

Tags: caching, ignite, rest

> I am Using Apache Ignite 2.8.0.
>   I have developed small dash board that is used to monitor the performance of Ignite.
>   Now my problem is finding the number of servers.
>   first i have find the total number of nodes(in node variable), then

```
    total_servers = 0
    port = 8080

    for j in range(0,node + 1):   
      if(persistence == True):
        url_cache = "http://localhost:" + str(port) + "/ignite?cmd=top&sessionToken=" +sessionToken

      else:
        url_cache = "http://localhost:" + str(port) + "/ignite?cmd=top"            
      try:
                    print(j)
                    try:
                        res = requests.get(url = url_cache)
                        print(res.status_code)
                        if(res.status_code == 200):
                             total_servers = total_servers + 1
                    except:
                        pass
      except:
             pass

      port = port + 1
```

> But it will take much time, i don't want that. 
>   is there any simple way to finding the number of servers running in Apache Ignite by using REST API http request?

Comment: Have you tried the #topology method? https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#topology

Comment: As for monitoring, you can use the WebConsole which is free to use https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/web-console-getting-started

Comment: i am using that also.. but i need history records. for example i need to show the records which has been happened previous week. so i have developed one tool using MySQL.

Comment: yes  i have tried top command. but there i didn't found the number of servers.

Comment: i have one doubt .. for client node tcpPort is always '0' .. am i right?

Comment: is it possible to monitor the history data like the CPU load of previous week on particular time by GridGain web console?

Comment: No, GridGain doesn't keep the historical data, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

From REST you can [run SQL command](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#sql-fields-query-execute) `SELECT * FROM SYS.NODES;` to determine that:

```
~/Downloads/apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin% wget -q -O- http://localhost:8080/ignite\?cmd=qryfldexe\&pageSize\=10\&cacheName\=default\&qry=select\ \*\ from\ sys.nodes | jq .response.items
[
  [
    "3304155a-bc83-402f-a884-59d39f074d3a",
    "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo,127.0.0.1,172.17.0.1,192.168.1.7:47500",
    "2.8.1#20200521-sha1:86422096",
    false,
    false,
    1,
    "[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 192.168.1.7]",
    "[192.168.1.7, 172.17.0.1]",
    true
  ]
]
```

(assumes you have cache named `default` for API purposes)

Comment: i got the following respose  {"successStatus":1,"error":"Failed to find cache with name: default","response":null,"sessionToken":null}

Comment: yes i got the correct response when i give any cache name (that exists in the cluster).  but without persistence initially i don't have any cache, on that time what name i need to give?

Comment: You need to create a cache, you can do with `cmd=getorcreate`

Comment: thank you alamar, i have updated my answer .. can you please check whether that is right way or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found one Answer.. if it's wrong please suggest me,

```
http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=node&id=a427-a04631d64c98&attr=true
```

> in response["attributes"]["org.apache.ignite.cache.client"] => false,

Comment: Yes, it should work by combining `top` and `node` commands' results.